# Manually trigger screen rotation in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I developed a Windows 8 Metro App. Now I wanted to test what happens if I rotate the screen but I do not have a device which is capable of this.

Is there a way to trigger this manually? I can rotate the screen manually with my ATI driver but I don't thinks this is what happens if I rotate some tablet?

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing, the [Simulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441475.aspx) in Visual Studio will enable you to do this.

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice tool. I didn't know it existed.

Comment: Note that although this is useful for testing things such as the reflow of your layout, it does not fully simulate a rotation event. It ignores your application's AutoRotationPreferences, and does not raise rotation events. As far as I know, testing on an actual device is the only way around those issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a video driver-dependent setting, but with the Windows 8 systems I've used, I could manually rotate the display via `Ctrl+Alt+arrow`. Left = 90 degrees, Down = 180, Right = 270.